# Unable to link the paypal transaction to order

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

I am not able to view the order details under my paypal seller or buyer account.  Find below the screenshot with explanation

Buyer is buying a package.  The order details are displayed at left side.
[image]

After the successful purchase, the seller is logging to his paypal account and he couldn't able to find the order details.  In the below page I could see the amount but not the cart details.
[image]

I am using express checkout to make the payment and I am storing the order details in the below variables and submitting to setexpresscheckout.

```
$order_line .= "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=".$packname;
$order_line .= "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=".$order_item_desc;
$order_line .= "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=".$packagePrice;
$order_line .= "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=".$paymentid;
$order_line .= "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1";

$order_line .= "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=".$packagePrice;
$order_line .= "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=".$packagePrice;
$order_line .= "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=".$currencyID;
```

Am I missing something?  How do I see the order details so that I can link each payment to the respective order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering to my own question.  To show the order details in the paypal transaction page, I need to set the below variables before doexpresscheckout.

```
$order_line .= "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=".$packname;
$order_line .= "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=".$order_item_desc;
$order_line .= "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=".$packagePrice;
$order_line .= "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=".$paymentid;
$order_line .= "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1";

$order_line .= "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=".$packagePrice;
$order_line .= "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=".$packagePrice;
$order_line .= "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=".$currencyID;
```

Previously I have these variables loaded only before setexpresscheckout and thats the reason it shown at left side of the login page.  After I set the same before doexpresscheckout now I am able to see the order details in the transaction page.